# Release file not found error encountered with Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I have seen some similar questions, but in my case the following error popped up when I ran `sudo apt-get update`:

```
ICON_lab) randychen@randychen-Delta-15-A5EFK:~/projects$ sudo apt-get update
Hit:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Get:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease [114 kB]     
Ign:3 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu jammy InRelease                       
Err:4 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu jammy Release                         
  404  Not Found [IP: 140.211.166.134 80]
Get:5 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease [99.8 kB]  
Get:6 http://www.deb-multimedia.org jessie InRelease [15.4 kB]                 
Hit:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease                         
Hit:8 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease               
Get:9 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [95.1 kB]
Get:10 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [257 kB]
Get:11 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [940 B]
Get:13 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [11.4 kB]
Ign:6 http://www.deb-multimedia.org jessie InRelease                           
Hit:12 https://packagecloud.io/slacktechnologies/slack/debian jessie InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu jammy Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: GPG error: http://www.deb-multimedia.org jessie InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 5C808C2B65558117
E: Release file for http://www.deb-multimedia.org/dists/jessie/InRelease is expired (invalid since 388d 20h 52min 20s). Updates for this repository will not be applied.
W: https://packagecloud.io/slacktechnologies/slack/debian/dists/jessie/InRelease: Key is stored in legacy trusted.gpg keyring (/etc/apt/trusted.gpg), see the DEPRECATION section in apt-key(8) for details.
```

At first I thought it's due to a PPA but I don't have any here. I tried trouble shooting it by following [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53801447/17389114), and I added that line of code on the top of the file, but it's not working either.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You have to correct the url:

```
sudo grep -rlF 'http://packages.ros.org' /etc/apt/sources* |
    xargs sed -i 's@http://packages.ros.org@https://ubuntu.osuosl.org/@'
sudo apt update
```

Comment: thanks for the response, but I get this error instead: ```sed: couldn't open temporary file /etc/apt/sources.list.d/sedSx1bj6: Permission denied
```

Comment: Try to decompose the commands one by one and understanding what you do at each step